# Find range of values between 2 columns in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle11g

Hi I have a table with 2 columns with range, so for e.g If Range Start = ABC1/000/0/0000 and Range END = ABC1/000/0/1022 .

I have to get all the values between this range and then join this with another table. Can you let me know how can I get all the values in DUAL table. I am using Oracle 11g.

Basically I need to make a list with first value as ABC1/000/0/0000 second as ABC1/000/0/0001 till ABC1/000/0/1022.

Comment: ?? What does that mean? "Range" means a sequence of values between a min and a max. By "Range1" and "Range2" you probably mean a single range, not two distinct ranges. But for each you give FOUR values, a string and three numbers. What "range" are you talking about? And how are FOUR values stored at once? Are they in a single column, just like that, as slash-separated strings?

Comment: Have you tried `between`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - joining to a table with individual values within a range, one value per row, is quite different from joining on a `between` condition.

Comment: ABC1/000/0/0000 is a single value stored in a column, this is basically a slash separated string. This is an example of range, in real senario there  could be more than 100K between Range Start and Range END. I have to store them temporarily like in DUAL and than join this list with another table

Comment: No, this is not an example of a range. Examples of ranges are: 1. Letters from A to K.  2. Numbers from 0 to 2000.  3. Dates from Jan-1-2013 to Jan-1-2014. What do you mean by "the range" ABC1/000/0/0000? If you use the word "range" with a meaning that is different from the usual, you need to explain what that is.

Comment: Wait - perhaps you don't mean "range" at all? Are you just asking how you can split the single-string ABC1/000/0/0000 into its components, make it "as if" there were four columns with the values ABC1, 000, 0 and 0000? That is a different and meaningful question, it just has nothing to do with "ranges".

Comment: My Question is, I have to get all the values which lie between ABC1/000/0/0000 and ABC1/000/0/1022 and join the result with another table. I need help in the query which would generate the list of values

Comment: @mathguy: basically make a list with first value as ABC1/000/0/0000 second as ABC1/000/0/0001 till ABC1/000/0/1022. I want help in the query to get this done

Comment: look at regexp_substr function

Comment: @OldProgrammer Thanks I will explore regexp_substr function

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you mean by "storing values temporarily in DUAL". DUAL is a singe column table with a single value!

However, something like this might be what you want. If its not, then perhaps you could elaborate on your problem a little further

```
select blah
from another_table
where somekey in
  ( select blah
    from table
    where col between <rangeStart> and <rangeEnd>
   )
```

Comment: As I explained in a comment (in response to another poster's comment which was similar to your answer): joining to a table that has one row per value in a range is not the same thing as joining on a `between` condition.

Comment: @mathguy I concur. But do you really know what Mr. Ramandeep is asking for? I does seem a little vague ;)

Comment: I think he clarified towards the end of the "comment exchange" under the original post. I will edit his post - I will copy that comment in the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems you need a few things.

1. Separate the "last value" from a slash-separated string, such as
   `ABC1/000/0/0000`. It is best to do this with standard `substr()` and
   `instr()` functions, not with regular expressions (for faster
   execution). In `instr()` we can use a negative argument for
   occurrence, to indicate "counting from the end of the string".
   Something like this:

   `select range_from, substr(range_from, instr(range_from, '/', -1) + 1
    from   ...`
2. Actually, you will need to convert this to a number with `to_number()` for further processing, and you will also need to capture the substring up to the last slash (similar use of `substr()` and `instr()`. And you will need to do the same for `range_to`.
3. Generate all the numbers from the first value to the last value. This is easily done with a `connect by level` query (hierarchical query). Some care must be taken since we may need to do this for several input rows (input ranges) at once.
4. Then put everything back together and use the result in further processing.

I will assume that the `range_from` string contains at least one slash, that the substring between the last slash and the end of the string represents a non-negative integer in character format, and the `range_to` similarly contains at least one slash and the substring from the last slash to the end of the string represents a non-negative integer. It is your responsibility to guarantee that this integer is greater than or equal to the one from `range_from`. In the output I will use the same substring UP TO the last slash as I find in `range_from`; if the requirement is that `range_to` must have the same initial substring, it is your responsibility to guarantee that.

I will also assume that the width (number of characters) of the "number" part (the last token in the strings) is not known beforehand and must be calculated in the query.

```
with
     test_data( id, range_from, range_to ) as (
       select 1, 'ABC1/000/0/2033', 'ABC1/000/0/2035' from dual union all
       select 2, 'xyz/33/200'     , 'xyz/33/200'      from dual union all
       select 3, '300/LMN/000'    , '300/LMN/003'     from dual
     )
--  end of test data; SQL query begins below this line
select id, stub || lpad(to_char(from_nbr + level - 1), len, '0') as val
from (
   select id, stub, length(from_str) as len, to_number(from_str) as from_nbr,
                                             to_number(to_str)   as to_nbr
   from ( 
      select id, substr(range_from, 1, instr(range_from, '/', -1))  as stub,
                 substr(range_from, instr(range_from, '/', -1) + 1) as from_str,
                 substr(range_to  , instr(range_to  , '/', -1) + 1) as to_str
      from test_data
   )
)
connect by level <= 1 + to_nbr - from_nbr
       and prior id = id
       and prior sys_guid() is not null
order by id, level                               --  if needed
;

ID VAL
-- --------------------
 1 ABC1/000/0/2033
 1 ABC1/000/0/2034
 1 ABC1/000/0/2035
 2 xyz/33/200
 3 300/LMN/000
 3 300/LMN/001
 3 300/LMN/002
 3 300/LMN/003
```